# Auto Complete TextBox Winforms Not Working

Tags: c#, winforms, autocomplete, textbox

I have been trying to get this to work and can not find why it will not. I have a loading form first which initializes everything then that form closes and the login form shows. The textbox for the username is supposed to get autocomplete values from config file. I can get all the values and it shows in the autocompletecustomsource but when I test it the textbox does not even show suggestions as I type. Here is the code I use to add all the form elements to the form. I have tried putting it in the onload overide as well as the initialization method.

```
[STAThread]
private void AddControls()
    {
        Label lb;
        TextBox tb;
        Button btn;

        lb = new Label()
        {
            AutoSize = true,
            Left = 5,
            Top = 5,
            Text = "Username:",
            Font = new Font(this.Font.FontFamily, 7, FontStyle.Italic)
        };
        this.Controls.Add(lb);
        tb = new TextBox()
        {
            Left = lb.Left,
            Top = lb.Bottom + 2,
            Width = this.Width - 10,
            Name = "user"
        };

        this.Controls.Add(tb);
        AutoCompleteStringCollection ASC = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
        ASC.AddRange(_DataHandler.CFManager.GetConfigValue(BPConfig.CFGVal.Users).Split(';'));
        tb.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
        tb.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
        tb.AutoCompleteCustomSource = ASC;
    }
```

Comment: Have you checked the actual content of your `AutoCompleteStringCollection`? Assign the collection to another array before passing it to the collection, so you can better verify what's in it (possibly, trailing spaces and/or empty lines).

Comment: Yes I did that. I verified there were no extra spaces or anything

Comment: You understand that what your `_DataHandler.CFManager.GetConfigValue()` is returning is known to you only. If I pass a simple array of strings to the `AutoCompleteStringCollection` using the same code you posted here, it works as expected.

Comment: I had the same problem with textbox, for me i was using multiline with textbox which was causing this issue. Changing multiline to false solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use **ComboBox**
Like TextBox => comboBox1.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.Simple

```
var list = new List<string>() { ... };

comboBox1.DataSource = list;
comboBox1.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.Simple;
comboBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
```